# MLModel gives a wrong output for not labeled data

Tags: ios, coreml, mlmodel

I got a problem with the output of my MLModel. For example I want to create a model with only two categorys, dogs and cats and nothing else. I am handing over a data folder with two sub folders, dog and cat.The dog folder such as the cat folder gets the same amount of pictures. Same for the test folder. When I embed the model into my Xcode and I am trying to take a picture of a dog or  a cat everything works fine, BUT when I try to make a picture of for example a keyboard I get "dog" as output with a confidence of over 99%. I just want to output unknown object instead of one of these two categorys.

I also tried to recreate the model with more loops and additionall augmentations but the result is still the same. I thinked of mayybe a default folder in the data folder and a test folder for other cases than dogs and cats,but I dont think that this is the right way for solving the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.